# How does this snippet of code create a ray direction vector?

Tags: opengl, minecraft-modding, lwjgl, raycasting

In the Minecraft source code, this code is used to create a direction vector for a ray from pitch and yaw:'

```
float f1 = MathHelper.cos(-rotationYaw * 0.01745329F - 3.141593F);
float f3 = MathHelper.sin(-rotationYaw * 0.01745329F - 3.141593F);
float f5 = -MathHelper.cos(-rotationPitch * 0.01745329F);
float f7 = MathHelper.sin(-rotationPitch * 0.01745329F);
return Vec3D.createVector(f3 * f5, f7, f1 * f5);
```

I was wondering how it worked, and what is the constant `0.01745329F`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works by using [spherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system).  In particular see the section about converting to Cartesian coordinates.  The Wikipedia article uses a slightly different convention for the definitions of the angles than your code, resulting in some sin / cos factors being swapped, but it's the same idea.

Answer (score 1):

0.01745329F is the conversion rate between degrees and radians. Degrees are easier to understand but most mathematical functions need radians so this is a common conversion to perform. The -pi part just rotates the value further.

I'll let someone else address the trigonometry part. :)